# No tests were executed! error in maven build using testNg

Tags: java, maven, testng

Am trying to execute following class with specific method using TestNg with maven.

Here iam using following terminal command to run the specified class.

```
mvn clean -Dtest=LaunchTest

public class LaunchTest  {    
    @Test
    public void launchHtml(){

        String WEBAPP_URL = "https://atee/public/index.html";        
         for (String ids : deviceIds){
            // operations
         }      
    }
    @Test
    public void launchsApp() throws TestException {

    String app = "unittest"
    /*
    operations
    */

    } 
}
```

but i need to execute class with specific methods like l`aunchHtml or launchsApp` also pass arguments from terminal commands

for eg :to execute the method `launchsApp()`

```
mvn clean -Dtest=LaunchTest#launchsApp
```

when i using the above command am getting following error

```
INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.
8.1:test (default-test) on project send-deeplink: No tests were executed!  (Set
-DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.) -> [Help 1]
ERROR]
ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
h.
ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Comment: Are you really using maven-surefire-plugin version 2.8.1 ?

Comment: @saathu please review all your question because there are missing stuff, first with the command `mvn clean -Dtest=LaunchTest` you cannot launch anything except the `clean` because you need to launch at least the **test** goal to run tests (for example `mvn clean test -Dtest=LaunchTest` to run your test), then copy at least a part of your `pom.xml` that could help to understand your configuration.

Comment: @saathu and also, there are missing characters in your log copy that are making it confusing (see @khmarbaise comment saying that you use the surefire plugin `2.8.1` while we can suppose that first column is missing in the copy and conclude that it could be `2.18.1` instead)